# Download is not tracking on web page in matomo

Tags: csv, download, tracking, matomo

I am trying to track download file in matomo but in the dashboard it is not reflecting
this is the reference `https://matomo.org/faq/new-to-piwik/faq_47/`

```
  _paq.push(['setLinkTrackingTimer', 750]); // 250 milliseconds
  _paq.push(['setDownloadExtensions', ".csv"]);
```

but it is not reflecting in the dashboard 
Tried creating goals for the same but same issue it is not reflecting in the dashboard

please let me know what has to be done to fix this

Answer (score 0):

Matomo by default, recognizes CSV files.

Adding   _paq.push(['setDownloadExtensions', ".csv"]); may break the functionality. Is your website a Single page app or normal HTML. What is the download URL?

Comment: i got do for both single page and normal html

Comment: in single page app i am using https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-csv no link as such

Comment: If that's the case, I would recommend you to try triggering an event everytime a visitor downloads the file. https://matomo.org/docs/event-tracking/

Comment: sorry forgot to update ya achieved the task using event-tracking

Answer (score 0):

If you're using SPA you need to instruct Matomo to scan the DOM for new content. We'll now go over various content types (Videos & Audio, Forms, Links and Downloads, Content tracking). Please review https://developer.matomo.org/guides/spa-tracking#making-matomo-aware-of-new-content and if file name is not passed in the URL param then please review https://developer.matomo.org/guides/tracking-javascript-guide#enabling-download-outlink-tracking

If you're using normal HTML, then it should work automatically, we recommend you to remove the 'setLinkTrackingTimer' and 'setDownloadExtensions' from the tracking code.